# Problems working with factors and apply functions

Tags: r, sapply

What I have is a data frame that contains, among others, a factor field which holds a range of values used as factor. From what I understand it is essentially bins for numeric values.

What I want to do is to convert these to numeric values so I can use them in the downstream analysis. The idea is simple enough; (a) get a function that takes the factor level, split it at the dash and extract numeric values and calculates the average and (b) apply the function of the column

```
data$Range.mean <- sapply(data$Range, 
                             function(d) {
                               range <- as.matrix(strsplit(as.character(d), "-"))
                               (as.numeric(range[,1]) + as.numeric(range[,2]))/2
                             })
```

Which gives the following error

```
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I tried `lapply` instead which makes no difference. While looking for answers, I found some other solutions to this problem, which is essentially extracting the lower and upper bound separately to individual arrays then of course calculating pairwise average is trivial.

I would like to understand what I am doing/thinking wrong here though. Why is my code giving an error, and what does that error mean, really?

Comment: perhaps `strsplit(as.character(d), "-")[[1]]`?

Comment: or, maybe, `unlist(strsplit(as.character(d), "-"))`?

Comment: @alexis_laz `unlist` seems to do the trick, together with changing the way I access the first and second element. Although I am still a bit confused as to why I got the error message in the first place. The error message is a bit cryptic to me.

Comment: In `?strsplit` you'll see that the value of this function is a `list`. `as.numeric` tries to be applied on a "`list`-y" object and gives this error.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in that factors in fact are integers with labeled bins. So if you have a factor like this

```
x <- factor(c("0-1", "0-1", "1-2", "1-2"))
```

it is essentially a combination of the following components

```
as.integer(x)
levels(x)
```

To convert the factor to the actual values specified by its lables, you can take a detour through `as.character` and parse that into numbers.

```
# Recreating a data frame with a factor like yours
data <- data.frame(Range = cut(runif(100), 0:10/10))
levels(data$Range) <- sub("\\((.*),(.*)]", "\\1-\\2", levels(data$Range))

# Calculating range means
sapply(strsplit(as.character(data$Range), "-"),
       function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))
```